# Mvc Model Bind in View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have a model..

```
Models.Mm.Items.ItemEditModel like thiss..
```

in ItemEdit View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RecordTypeId) --> this works bind model and take value RecordTypeId

@Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(m => m.RecordTypeId) --> this works

<input id="RecordTypeId" name="RecordTypeId" type="text" /> --> this not working this value is null
```

I am using autofac and kendo.

I could not understand why html binding not working..

Comment: Do you mean its not posting back, or its not showing the value of `RecordTypeId` (because you have not set the attribute `value=@Model.RecordTypeId`)?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information here to give you the real cause of the problem, but one thing you can check is the name attribute of the input element generated by the first two methods.

Mvc use the name attribute to bind your model so if this name does not match what he expect for the property of the mod

Comment: Real Cause is Recordtype value don't seem when if I use <input name="RecordTypeId"/> but mvc or kendo helper using for example  this works..     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RecordTypeId) value seems in input..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you talking about the initial value when the page is loaded for the first time? If its the case its because you never set it. The helpers method are equivalent to <input id="RecordTypeId" name="RecordTypeId" type="text" value="@Model.RecordTypeId" />

Comment: This works but I want to bind with name only. it shouold bind with name.. ı mustn't write more code for binding must it? Default it binds with name only but here don't work.. Why?

Comment: The helper methods are getting the name of the property from the lambda you provide but they are also getting the value of the property so they are able to do both steps, setting the name and the value, automatically for you. When you write the input yourself mvc has no way to know what you really want do with this input, you might want to bind the input to the property but not display the initial value (for a password for example) and in this case you would set the right name but not the value attribute.